# How can I use JavaScript & jQuery with Microsoft's new Sharepoint that uses TypeScript?

Tags: jquery, typescript, sharepoint

I'm using Yeoman to make a Sharepoint webpart.  This is the generator I'm using '@microsoft/sharepoint'.

This creates a bunch of typescript files.

This is a slider I wish to use to build my web part: https://www.npmjs.com/package/slider-pro

All it uses is jQuery.  The instructions for using it seem to show how you would go about creating it with a regular old HTML file but I'm unsure of how to do this in the environment that Yeoman setup for me.

Is there I way I can use this if I need to keep all of the typescript?

Let me know if there is anything else I can add to make this question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write JavaScript code in TypeScript file. JavaScript is a subset of TypeScript, therefore it will be executed correctly.

Comment: I was told that as well by one of my coworkers.  However I saw this on Microsoft's website: "

    Note: Because you're using TypeScript, you need typings for the package you add. This is essential when you are writing code because TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript. All the TypeScript code is still converted to JavaScript code when you compile. You can search for and find typings by using tsd package, for example: tsd install {package} --save
"   https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/basics/add-an-external-library

Comment: You only _may_ use 'typings' for TypeScript code. For JavaScript there is no typings, because they are not needed for JavaScript. Typings is the source for IntelliSence functionality for TypeScript. Typings is what makes TypeScript typed (sorry for the tautology :) ). So, just use your regular JavaScript code to manipulate jQuery , the only thing that can help you is to add "declare var $;" in the beginning of the TypeScript file so that it knows that '$' symbol is declared somewhere outside TypeScript code and does not break the TypeScript compilation.

Comment: Thanks @Burst  One more question if you don't mind.  I'm new to TypeScript.. is there no HTML file at all?  Like for referencing external files or libraries?  Does all that need to be done through TypeScript?

Comment: The SharePoint Framework solution is a bunch of CSS, HTML, JavaScript files. TypeScript is "compiled" (transformed) to pure JavaScript. TypeScript makes the writing of the code easier (intellisence, type checking, etc.), but TypeScript only exists as the source code. What is executed in the browser is JavaScript that is the result of TypeScript transformation into JS. So if SPFx doesn't include any HTML files, that means that all the display templates are included as strings inside JavaScript when it's executed in the browser. Just get to know frameworks like ReactJS or just review MS' samples